# I am trying to run AR app in android studio but, while adding fragment i am getting error "missing constraint and unknown fragment"

Tags: android

I have code as in this image

[image]
error1:
A  tag allows a layout file to dynamically include different layouts at runtime. At layout editing time the specific layout to be used is not known. You can choose which layout you would like previewed while editing the layout.
-  (Pick Layout...)
 Do not warn about  tags in this session

error2:
This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints  The layout editor allows you to place widgets anywhere on the canvas, and it records the current position with designtime attributes (such as layout_editor_absoluteX). These attributes are not applied at runtime, so if you push your layout on a device, the widgets may appear in a different location than shown in the editor. To fix this, make sure a widget has both horizontal and vertical constraints by dragging from the edge connections.  Issue id: MissingConstraints

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If you ask a question, they are a lot easier to read if you include the code you have a question about directly. The image link does not really work. You can use ``` to mark the beginning and end of your code block.

Answer (score 0):

Just add those lines to `<fragment>` tag:

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

For more info on ConstraintLayout, see [this](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout).